# Show Binary Image in Html Table from Code Behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am creating a table which should read binary image from DB and display in Html table.

My Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Table Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .small-ad-wrapper{width:215px;height:195px;overflow:hidden;}
        .small-ad-wrapper .portfolio-img-control{width:204px;height:134px;overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:3px;}
    </style>    

</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdCreate" OnClick="cmdCreate_Click" runat="server" Text="Create" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Table ID="tbl" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Code Behind:

```
StringBuilder htmlTable = new StringBuilder();
htmlTable.Append("<table border='1'>");
htmlTable.Append(@"<tr style='background-color:green; color: White;'>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                </tr>");

int i = 1;
foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        htmlTable.Append("<tr style='color: White;'>");
    }

    htmlTable.Append("<div class='portfolio-img-control'>");

    byte[] bytes = (byte[])(byte[])row["LogoFile"];
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgNew = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    imgNew.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

    htmlTable.Append("<td>" + imgNew + "</td>");

    htmlTable.Append("</div");
    if (i == 3)
    {
        htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
        i = 1;
    }
    else
        i = i + 1;
}

htmlTable.Append("</table>");
DBDataPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlTable.ToString() });

htmlTable.Append("<tr>");
htmlTable.Append("<td align='center' colspan='4'>There is no Record.</td>");
htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
```

But it gives me result "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image" and doesnt show image at all.

How to do this? Please reply Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you create a new asp.net image control, and try to use the object as string.

These lines must be remove...

```
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgNew = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    imgNew.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;    
    htmlTable.Append("<td>" + imgNew + "</td>");
```

if you like to render it as string, must be change as:

```
htmlTable.AppendFormat("<td><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,{0}\"></td>", base64String);
```

Please note, I do not know if the rest of your code is bug free...